# Windows Phone 8.1 ScrollViewer disable overscroll effect

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

How to disable overscroll effects of ScrollViewer for Windows Phone 8.1? And how to disable overzoom/overpinch effect?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this effect is inherent to the `ScrollViewer` behaviour and is made by design, so that there is no easy and fast method to do this, if any.

I would recommend you follow the same design guidelines as this will create a consistent user experience.

Comment: May be it's possible to handle scrolling events, detect offset and if it becomes out of bounds cancel such events?